# get Distinct records after Concat Clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

i have this mysql Query

```
   SELECT  DISTINCT CONCAT ('US-',  medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Provider State`) AS `Provider State`,
                                    ROUND(medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Total Discharges`, 2) AS `Total Discharges`
                                    FROM medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011
                                    WHERE medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Provider Name` LIKE '%ELK REGIONAL HEALTH CENTER'
                                     limit 0,5
```

what i am trying to do is that i want to fetch state name cocncat 'US' with it and then get distinct states based on rest of the query.

Edit this is the out put

```
  State   Total
  US-PA     18
  US-PA     16
  US-PA     27
  US-PA     39
  US-PA     42
```

and suggested output should be something like this

```
  State   Total
  US-NY     18
  US-WD     16
  US-TX     27
  US-AZ     39
  US-CA     42
```

Comment: What's the output you getting??

Comment: i will place output in my question.

Comment: And what should the output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try summing up the total discharges and grouping by the provider state.

```
SELECT CONCAT ('US-',  medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Provider State`) AS `Provider State`,
                                sum(ROUND(medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Total Discharges`, 2)) AS `Total Discharges`
                                FROM medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011
                                WHERE medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Provider Name` LIKE '%ELK REGIONAL HEALTH CENTER'
GROUP BY CONCAT ('US-',  medicare_provider_charge_inpatient_drg100_fy2011.`Provider State`)
                                 limit 0,5
```

Comment: i am getting only 1 row as out put with group by clause:
this is the output i have `US-PA 1063`

Comment: I would check your where clause and make sure that the like condition is getting everything you expect.

Comment: My mistake i didnt checked the whole out put, your answer is correct, thx mate.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

Comment: this should be a comment